# How to fix Django 'Can't find msguniq' error

Tags: django, internationalization

I try to use internationalization in my Django project

I follow a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xI97sLMd1rM but author skip the configuration for gettext

I have installed gettext librairie and seems to be OK: xgettext --session in a prompt confirm it is installed

And I follow beginning of the tutorial

settings.py

```
LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'locale'),
]
```

base.html

```
{% load static i18n %}
{% load static %} # don't know if should import twice static
```

test_translation.html

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
h2>{% trans "A test of translation" %}</h2>
```

however, when I run in my env

> (env) PS myproject > django-admin makemessages -l fr

I got the following error:

> CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.

Do I need to install somethings else?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why but the problem comes from that I try to execute django-admin makemessages -l fr form my VS Code console instead of prompt console...

if anybody can explain me the difference I would appreciate...